# Forcing docker client (CLI) to use HTTP instead of HTTPS

Tags: docker, docker-daemon

I have a Docker daemon hosted in Ubuntu
and I would like to access it from Windows with Docker CLI:

```
C:\Users\Plus>docker -H tcp://192.168.3.2:2375 images
error during connect: Get https://192.168.3.2:2375/v1.40/images/json: http: server gave HTTP response to HTTPS client
```

It seems the Docker client wants to connect to the server with HTTPS
Can I force it to connect with HTTP?

I can get my image info from browser/curl with HTTP:

```
C:\Users\Plus>curl http://192.168.3.2:2375/v1.40/images/json
[{"Containers":-1,"Created":1610677431,"Id":"sha256:7731472c3f2......
```

---

Docker client version: `Docker version 1.12.0, build 8eab29e`
Windows: `Windows 7 Ultimate`
Docker server version: `Docker version 20.10.2, build 2291f61`
Ubuntu (Docker server): `20.04`

Comment: Remember that anyone who can connect to the Docker socket can launch a container, as root, bind-mounting anything they want from the host filesystem; it's really easy to use this to root the host.  I'd turn off the remote Docker socket setting _now_, and evaluate whether the system has already been compromised.